# javascript: get all object parameters

Tags: javascript, object, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a JS object with a variable number of parameters. Is there a way to see what parameters have been passed this particular time?

The example:

```
function getElement() {
    var scope = document;

    this.by = function(data){
        if (data.id)    scope = scope.getElementById(data.id);
        if (data.tag)   scope = scope.getElementsByTagName(data.tag);       
        return scope;
    }
}
```

And I run it like so

```
var x = new getElement(); 
vad div = x.by({id : "chosenID"});
```

gets the div with the id `chosenID`

or

```
var x = new getElement(); 
vad inputs = x.by({id : "chosenID", tag : "input"});
```

gets all the `inputs` in the div with the id `chosenID`;

I want to know if I passed one or two parameters, and which ones.

Thanks!

ps: I appreciate your time in helping me out, but please do not sugget jQuery or other JS framework as this is for learning purposes only. Much obliged, Sorin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [`for … in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to iterate over the passed object's parameters, like:

```
var prop;

for (prop in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        // do something with data[prop]
    }
}
```

Don't forget to check the property with [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

Comment: Should this be `for (var prop in data)`?

Comment: @SamSelikoff No, `prop` is already declared with local scope using `var`.

Comment: Ah, is there a difference between the two ways?

Comment: @SamSelikoff No, `for (var prop in data)` is shorthand for `var prop; for (prop in data)`.

Comment: Sorry to dig this up, but doesn't `for (prop in data)` assume each `prop` exists in `data`?  Why the check?

Comment: @SeanKendle To check if a property is owned by `data` or if it is inherited. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty): “This method can be used to determine whether an object has the specified property as a direct property of that object; unlike the `in` operator, this method does not check down the object's prototype chain.”

Answer (score 1):

Using object iteration (`key in data`) and array-combining... you can return a number of elements... although the object iteration is rendered pretty useless by by the switch statement.

```
function getElement() {
    var scope = document;
    this.by = function(data){
        var key;
        var ret=[];
        for (key in data) {
          if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            switch(key) {
              case "id":
                ret=ret.concat(scope.getElementById(data[key]));
                break;
              case "tag":
                ret=ret.concat(scope.getElementsByTagName(data[key]));
                break;
              default:
                throw new Error("Unknown property "+key);
            }
          }
        }
        return ret;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of good *general* answers, however consider this:

So, instead, I will cover some specific cases.
First off, I generally start with:

```
function f (x) {
  x = x || {} // so f() will be accepted as per f({})
  ...
}
```

This also sets up the context for the following.

My normal approach is just to check for a truth-y value. A true value means "supplied". However this has the disadvantage of not treating 0 or '' as "supplied".

```
if (x.id) {
   // x.id is any truth-y
}
```

If 0 is an accepted input then I widen the check so that non-`undefined` values are considered "supplied". An unset property always defaults to `undefined`. (This method will accept all truth-y values and false-y values such as 0, "", and `null`).

```
if (x.id !== undefined) {
   // x.id is all truth-y and all-but-undefined false-y
}
```

If `undefined` is an accepted input (*which I would strongly argue against*), then the check can be based on `hasOwnProperty`. This has the dis-advantage of not checking up the `[[prototype]]` chain.

```
if (x.hasOwnProperty("id")) {
   // x.id set to something, including undefined
}
```

The `for(..in..)` construct can also be used to iterate over the properties in an object (including properties in the `[[prototype]]` unless they are specially hidden). However, for the general case of dealing with input (e.g. not creating a JSON library), I find it is simple and clean just to deal with the properties on the input object(s) in one of the methods described above.